# whats the feature provided by visual basic 2005 to prevent conflicting modules?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005

I have noticed that I cant use the variable percentage in one module and a different variable called percentage in another module how can you do that without a conflict occurring?

Answer (score 2):

Modules add variables to the namespace they appear in.  Which is usually the global namespace so a collision between variable names is common.  VB.NET provides the Namespace keyword to solve this.  You'll have to write it like this:

```
Namespace Something
    Module whatever
       Dim Percentage As Double
    End Module
End Namespace
```

And modify the code that uses that variable but is not inside the namespace, if any, by writing `Something.Percentage`